# How to failover if Varnish is between HAProxy and Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, haproxy, varnish

I am thinking about putting Varnish inbetween HAProxy and Apache. That is working, however with Varnish inbetween HAProxy is monitoring Varnish. If Apache goes down it will not failover to the other Apache.

Is there a configuration in HAProxy which will overcome this problem?

Answer (score 1):

If Varnish is between HAproxy and Apache, you can just have Varnish do the [load-balancing](https://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/LoadBalancing), though it's not nearly as robust as the options provided by HAproxy.

What might be better would be to have HAproxy send static content to Varnish and the rest directly to the backend servers.

Haproxy.com has a very good article on how to do it [here](http://blog.haproxy.com/2012/08/25/haproxy-varnish-and-the-single-hostname-website/).

If you really want HAproxy to check the status of Varnish *and* Apache at the same time (which are on the same host), you have two options:

1. Setup dummy backends/servers in HAProxy which check Apache and have the matching Varnish server track the dummy:

   ```
   frontend HTTP-IN
     mode http
     default_backend Varnishes

   # All traffic goes here
   backend Varnishes
     mode http
     balance roundrobin 
     server Varnish-1 1.1.1.1:80 track Apache-1/Apache-1
     server Varnish-2 2.2.2.2:80 track Apache-2/Apache-2

   # No traffic ever goes here
   # Just used for taking servers out of rotation in 'backend Varnishes'
   backend Apache-1
     server Apache-1 1.1.1.1:8080 check

   backend Apache-2
     server Apache-2 2.2.2.2:8080 check
   ```
2. Have Varnish return a health check result that matches Apache's status (OK if Apache is up, FAILED otherwise).

   *varnish.vcl*

   ```
   backend default {
     .host = "127.0.0.1";
     .port = "8080";
   }

   # Health Check
   if (req.url == "/varnishcheck") {
     if (req.backend.healthy) {
       return(synth(751, "OK!"));
     } else {
       return(synth(752, "FAILED!"));
     }
   }

   sub vcl_synth {
     # Health Checks
     if (resp.status == 751) {
       set resp.status = 200;
       return (deliver);
     }
     if (resp.status == 752) {
       set resp.status = 503;
       return (deliver);
     }
   }
   ```

   *haproxy.cfg*

   ```
   frontend HTTP-IN
     mode http
     default_backend Varnishes

   backend Varnishes
     mode http
     balance roundrobin 
     option httpchk HEAD /varnishcheck
     http-check expect status 200
     server Varnish-1 1.1.1.1:80 check
     server Varnish-2 2.2.2.2:80 check
   ```

Comment: I was looking into the same article and setup but IMO HAProxy is the better load balancer. Therefore I am looking for a solution that will allow HAProxy to helthcheck apache and varnish in the same time. I get about double the requests per s if varnish is inbetween. The only thing missing is failover.

Comment: Do you have a single Varnish instance, or one per Apache node?

Comment: One per Apache  node on each machine

Comment: Updated answer to match what you want.